# Ignore projects in Git for Azure deployement

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, github-actions, class-library

I have a git repository where I have set up my code: 1 ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and 2 Class Library projects (.NET Framework 4.7.2). These are all in git on the master branch (I have no other branches) obviously with the 3 project folders and a .sln file, etc.

When I pick Continuous Deployement from Azure Deployement Center, pick my repo and branch (master), the build fails on a Class Library project (on the Git Action), and so nothing is deployed. I picked a .NET Core 3.1 runtime stack for my app service in Azure.

The manual deploy from Visual Studio (on the ASP.NET Core project ofc) works. But I'd like to have an automated build and deploy whenever I make a commit.

What are my options here? Can I somehow exclude the class library projects? I still need the dlls, because the ASP.NET Core project depends on them. I'm a total beginner here sorry if this sounds dumb.

Comment: In the Deployment Center what source control option (Azure Repos, GitHub, etc) are you selecting and which build provider are you selecting after that?

Comment: GitHub (link account), then GitHub Actions, then I fill the repository and branch. The commit is added and I can see on Actions on Git that it's building. But then if fails because of a class Library Project when building.

Comment: You should be able to edit the GitHub action workflow to exclude that project, though if it's failing to build on it's own when you try to build the project that references it I'd expect that to fail to.  It might be better to fix the error that's causing the build to fail.  Can you edit your question to include the error(s) the build is throwing?